# 'react-native run-android' giving "BUILD FAILED"

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to build an app on a virtual device from Android Studio. I followed all these steps
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
And I ran the virtual device before running "react-native start" and "react-native run-android"
[image]

`react-native start` was successful but I get the following error when I run `react-native run-android`

```
warn Package expo-modules-core has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: "dependency.platforms.ios" must be of type object
warn Package react-native-reanimated has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated\package.json'
Require stack:
 *[...]*
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:43872) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 1883 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
The system cannot find the path specified.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
?? react-native-unimodules is deprecated in favor of expo
?? Follow this guide to migrate: https://expo.fyi/expo-modules-migration


> Configure project :expo

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
*[...]*

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
*[...]*

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_firestore
*[...]*

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_messaging
*[...]*

> Configure project :react-native-mmkv
*[...]*
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level> 
*[...]*
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}api-level>
*[...]*
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}vendor>,<{}codename>,<{}abi>,<{}api-level>,<{}tag>
*[...]*
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}vendor>,<{}codename>,<{}abi>,<{}api-level>,<{}tag>

> Task :expo:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
178 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 175 up-to-date
Error: `expo-modules-core` project is not included by autolinking.
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (6, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (9, 31): Unresolved reference: ApplicationLifecycleListener
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 66): Unresolved reference: ApplicationLifecycleListener
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (14, 16): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (14, 21): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners   
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (15, 27): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (10, 21): Unresolved reference: adapters
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (11, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (12, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (17, 31): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryAdapter
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (26, 33): Unresolved reference: ModulePriorities
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (16, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (24, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (24, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityLifecycleListeners   
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (26, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (26, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityHandlers
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (37, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (76, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (83, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (89, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (96, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (120, 12): Unresolved reference: ReactActivityLifecycleListener
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (128, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (22, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (22, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactNativeHostHandlers
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (27, 29): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (32, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (35, 29): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (66, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (72, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (94, 31): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Error: `expo-modules-core` project is not included by autolinking.
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (6, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (9, 31): Unresolved reference: ApplicationLifecycleListener
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 66): Unresolved reference: ApplicationLifecycleListener
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (14, 16): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (14, 21): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners   
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (15, 27): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (10, 21): Unresolved reference: adapters
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (11, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (12, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (17, 31): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryAdapter
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (26, 33): Unresolved reference: ModulePriorities
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (16, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (24, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (24, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityLifecycleListeners   
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (26, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (26, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityHandlers
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (37, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (76, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (83, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (89, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (96, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (120, 12): Unresolved reference: ReactActivityLifecycleListener
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (128, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (22, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (22, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactNativeHostHandlers
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (27, 29): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (32, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (35, 29): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (66, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (72, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\expo\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (94, 31): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s

    at makeError (C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Oroni\Documents\Lets-Go-main\Lets-Go-main\LetsGo-React-Native\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I'm pretty lost at this point- I'm not sure where the `:expo:compileDebugKotlin` error is coming from and how to resolve it, and I'm not sure why the errors are saying they're failing to launch an emulator when I had the device open already. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Note: I had too many characters so I used *[...]* in the error messages to replace a bunch of files that were listed

Comment: what your project expo sdk number ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not sure which version of expo SDK my project is using

Comment: check your react-native version . expo sdk version dependent on react-native version.

Comment: I believe I'm using react-native version 0.64.3

Comment: your expo sdk version is 43 or 44. you need migrate the dependency and remove deprecated package such as  react-native-unimodules .

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you mean by migrating the dependency- could you please clarify?

Comment: read expo official doc and search migrating your sdk version to latest sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the SDK version settings in the React native docs. You need to select exactly same version of SDKs as mentioned in the docs otherwise build will fail.

Let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Hi, sorry but do you have a link to those docs?

Comment: I currently have the following checked in the SDK Platforms section:
- Android SDK Platform 30 and Sources for Android 30 under Android 11.0 (R)
- Android SDK Platform 29, Sources for Android 29, Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, and Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image under Android 10.0 (Q)

Comment: My build still fails, I have no clue what's wrong